# Keyboard shortcuts not grabbed by gnome-settings-daemon

Tags: 16.04, gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have set up some hotkeys through System Settings, but they are not working. I have verified that hey are present in the dconf database, in /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/.

I have run gnome-settings-daemon manually and the shortcuts still do no work. I also uninstalled appmenu-qt5.

How can I debug this problem? I will provide any additional information needed.

Edit: I also ran xev, and the Keys are captured by xev.